# How to mock numpy.linalg in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, mocking

I want to mock the linear algebra module in the numpy package, and I've been trying the following:

```
from mock import MagicMock
sys.modules["numpy.linalg"] = MagicMock()
import numpy.linalg
```

And I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 167, in <module>
from . import linalg
ImportError: cannot import name 'linalg'
```

It seems that while mock works with imports of the form:

```
import numpy.linalg
```

it isn't able to mock imports of the form:

```
from numpy import linalg
```

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Something does not seem right. Can you provide more context on how exactly you are mocking? It would help to see the module you have your unittests set up in, and how exactly you are calling your code to test

Comment: @ldjaw Actually, I'm not using mock for unit testing, I'm building a Windows executable and want to reduce the size of the executable by mocking the linear algebra module in numpy, which I don't need. Not sure if this is the best approach at all.

Comment: `numpy` isn't loaded piecemeal.  If I import `numpy`, `numpy.linalg` is available without further importing.  It's `scipy` that does the piecemeal submodule importing.

Comment: @hpaulj Good to know, thanks. However, `__init__.py` still contains `from . import linalg` calls - is there no way to mock these imports?

Comment: @matk out of curiosity. Did you get this working?

Comment: @ldjaw No, instead I'm pursuing virtualenv as a possible solution.